# Git Lab CI/CD pipeline not loading my entire ~/.bash_profile in my server when I ssh into it

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm using Saas version of GitLab, I set up my bash_profile to be

```
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# nvim alias
alias vim='nvim'
export EDITOR='nvim'

export GOPROXY=https://mirrors.aliyun.com/goproxy/

eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

but when I ssh into my shell using Gitlab's CI/CD pipeline (they are using Ruby 2.6 as base image), only some bash_profile is loaded in. Like nvm is not available...

I find this super strange... However when I ssh into the server using my own computer, everything works as expected, all bash_profile is logged in.

I tried to echo $SHELL in my CI/CD pipeline after ssh and did get /bin/bash. I have no idea what the issue is...

Comment: Can you show us how your initialising the ssh connection and also the relevant part of your CI file

Comment: Also perhaps more importantly: your runner configuration, which user is running it and does that user also have that bash profile or the different one you're reporting?

Comment: and just a note: don't put things for interactive use into the runner configuration. what i mean specficially are aliases. but also using nvm as in a pipeline you can just take care that node is in the pinned version. but that line is perhaps not that clear, I've also used nvm in some CI setups. it's just that was for getting it functional and not yet for doing it right.